# Images are uploaded to a different directory than shown in the background:URL style

Tags: media, uri

We've just had to take over the hosting for a Drupal site and I've moved the site across and everything seemed OK. BUT, whenever I try to upload a new image it gets saved in a different directory to where it should.

So the background:URL("") inline style is looking for the image here:
/sites/default/files/styles/segment_background_image/public/file.jpg

When the file is actually saved here:
/sites/default/files/file.jpg

I know absolutely nothing about Drupal and reading other peoples issues is just hours of not understanding a word. Any help would be hugely appreciated.

EDIT: To be more specific, the image doesn't display on the site because the inline style is looking in the wrong directory. It's an inline style, background:url("path"), where the path is different to where it is actually saved.

Answer (score 2):

That's all correct, you don't need to change anything.

Images under /sites/default/files/styles are *derivatives*, auto-generated by the system from [image styles](http://redcrackle.com/blog/how-create-and-use-drupal-7-image-styles) when first requested.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific:
The image doesn't display on the site because the inline style is looking in the wrong directory. It's an inline style, background:url("path"), where the path is different to where it is actually saved.

Comment: Given that you have an actual image style with the name segment_background_image, Drupal will create that image from your uploaded image once you first request it.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't appear to be happening. I've loaded the the page, cleared caches, done what I can to get it to request the image, but it's just just in the files folder

Comment: What response do you get for the image when you visit it directly? 403? 404? 500?

Comment: The console shows 500 on the page, accessing the image directly gives 403 in the console and the page shows "You are not authorized to access this page."

Comment: The 403 makes sense, image style urls have a token appended to them. The 500 will be the key to fixing this though - check the server logs, they will tell you what's specifically going wrong. It's commonly file permissions

Answer (score 0):

It was all to do with the new server and it's PHP.ini. Not enough memory, upped that and all of my problems were solved.

Thanks for helping though, confirmed that Drupal was working as it should!